# Keeping environment variables on window split

Tags: docker, virtualenv, environment, tmux

I use `virtualenv` and `docker` in my current development set. Both tools work by setting environment variables in the shell.

I would like to be able to keep those environment variables once I split the current window.

[image]

I believe this is a common case in many developers workflow and I would like to know if there is a default solution within `tmux` or if a custom configuration when splitting the pane is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `docker-machine`, add the eval statement to your shell rc file, like `~/.bashrc`. This assumes a machine name of `default`.

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

From the documentation you can see this will set the correct `ENV` variables:

https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/#/create-a-machine

> As noted in the output of the docker-machine create command, you need
>   to tell Docker to talk to the new machine. You can do this with the
>   docker-machine env command.

```
$ docker-machine env default
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://172.16.62.130:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/<yourusername>/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Comment: This is very convenient if that's the only environment you are using. Sadly, that's not my case, I have a "dev" environment and a "staging" environment.

Also, this doesn't applies to my python virtualenv. The idea is that the source window where I am splitting has the _correct environments_ and I want those to be applied to the new pane, not some default ones.